# How do I enumerate an object based on nodes in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, operators, nodes, enumeration

Say I constructed an Integer Node like so:

```
Node<Integer> node = new Node<Integer>(0, new Node<Integer>(1, new Node<Integer>(2, null)));
```

And get a node that looks like "0 ---> 1 ---> 2".

My objective is that when I run a command like `node = node * 4 + 28;` , node will look like "28 ---> 32 ---> 36", **WITHOUT** using functions such as `multiply(...)`.

That is, `node = node * 4 + 28` and not `node.multiply(4); node.add(28);` (unless it's used as a private function in a larger parsing function - a function I'd like to avoid if possible.)

Is there a way to enumerate nodes and other data structures (like Queue and Stack) like that in Java?

(Small note: Node itself is generic. It doesn't have to work with Strings, though. It'd be really nice if it did, though.)

Thanks in advance!

For those interested, Node looks like this:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T info;
    private Node<T> next;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What about recursion?

Comment: [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

Comment: @RC: If you're talking about a node which "never ends", I make the assumption that there's no recursion. If you're talking about using recursion - I first need to know how to perform the desired actions on a node "member"...

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Node {
    private int value = 0;
    private Node next = null;
...
    public void multiply(int num) {
        value *= num;
        if (next != null)
            next.multiply(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing to be wary of here is circular references getting you stuck in an endless recursion loop until you hit a StackOverflowError.  That can be avoided (at a cost) by adding each node to a collection after it is handled but before calling `next.multiply` and only calling `next.multiply` if `next` is not in the collection of handled nodes.  Alternatively, if circular references are by design not allowed, one could check for circular references at the time `next` is assigned a value and throw an IllegalArgumentException if a circular reference is found.

Comment: I actually didn't think about the case of an endless recurstion loop, thanks!

Comment: @user3053080 That's recursion (i.e. multiply is calling itself until a condition is met)

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant "endless recursion loop" in the sense that a "node-chain" may keep calling itself over and over again if you set a node's `next` value to another node in the same chain.

Answer (score 1):

If I get the question right, the function you're looking for is usually called map and it's not present in Java itself.

However, it's a paradigm commonly used in functional programming, so you might want to check e.g. [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) which offers a bunch of functional features to Java users.